Docker container to accessing host and internal network
I am confused on how you set up a docker container so that you can access both your host network and an internal network of containers?
Ex let's say you want container 1 to act as a proxy between internal containers network and outside.
How is this done?

A container can access services on the host network without any additional configuration.
To provide your host -- or other hosts on your network -- access to containerized services, you would typically publish a container port on the host. E.g., if you have a frontend proxy and then a number of internal backend containers, your proxy container would publish a port to the host...
docker run --name frontend -p 8080:80 ...

...so that you can access the proxy at http://<some_address_of_the_host>:8080.
See the documentation here for more information and examples.

So does the -p argument override the argument to have the container run on the internal network?

No. It sets up port forwarding from the host port to the container port. The container continues to run on the internal container network.

Ok, so the internal network is still up except for the ports listed in the -p command which go directly to host?

No. Nothing about the container changes. Your application continue to listen on their ports on the internal network. Port publishing sets up port forwarding on the host -- so that connections to the specified host port will be forwarded/proxied to the appropriate container port (generally through the application of some netfilter rules by the docker daemon).
